# change variable value outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
$(".outerdiv .innerdiv").hover(function(){
    var variable = $(this).index();
});
var variable = 3;
$("span").html(variable);
```

the original html of `<span>` is set as 3 using jquery but when hovering over an `.innerdiv` i want it to change to its index value by changing the variables outside the function to the index value of the specific `.innerdiv` that was hovered on. ​http://jsfiddle.net/eEUeT/9/

```
<div class="outerdiv">
    <div class="innerdiv">1</div>
    <div class="innerdiv">2</div>
    <div class="innerdiv">3</div>
    <div class="innerdiv">4</div>
    <div class="innerdiv">5</div>
</div>    
<span></span>​
```

I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/eEUeT/11/ this does not have a set orginal value of 3 however.

---

**AND** i understand by changing the html to `<span>3</span>` and using the jquery below will work but i would rather learn how to do it the way i asked

```
$(".outerdiv .innerdiv").hover(function(){
    var variable = $(this).index();
$("span").html(variable);
});
```

Comment: @DidierGhys I'm not stupid... That is why i asked how it's done. i never said this doesn't work...get your facts right. and you don't deserve 3 great comment votes.

Comment: I did not mean that and I did obsviously not voted my own comment up. Sorry if that offended you that was not my intent. According to your question it seemed you expected that behavior though.

Comment: :) Sorry if --I-- came across offensive. this isn't something i need. it's something i am using to learn how the .index() works but it's simple. so i thought i'd change it up by learning how to set a variable from outside a function. i generally ask how it's done after failing attempts myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate an element, you have to select it... you can't assign a value to a variable and expect the DOM element to update itself. As you stated though, it's easily enough done like this:

```
//set the initial HTML for the span element(s)
var $span = $('span').html(3);

$(".outerdiv .innerdiv").hover(function(){

    //update the span element(s) HTML to the index of the hovered-over `.innerdiv` element
    $span.html($(this).index());
});
```

​

This places the index of the hovered-over `.innerdiv` element as the HTML of any `<span>` elements.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eEUeT/14/